How to correctly update node.js in an ionic project
I have a project using vue / vuetify which I am attempting to merge into an Ionic project (the latter started out as a sample from the Ionic site).
The original project is working OK and uses vue version 3.4 . The Ionic project uses Vue version 3.3, which is no good for me. So I try to update vue:
PS C:\Users\quilk\source\repos\ionic\wordwheel> npm update vue

but this results in the following error:
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: wordwheel@0.0.1
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: wordwheel@0.0.1
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"npm":">=9.0.0 <10.0.0","node":">=20.0.0 <21.0.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"9.6.3","node":"v19.9.0"}

I have three versions of node installed, and I have asked to use version 20:
PS C:\Users\quilk\source\repos\ionic\wordwheel> nvm ls

20.8.1
18.12.1
16.19.0

After looking for suggestions on SO, I added this to package.json, but it didn't help
"engines" : { 
"npm" : ">=9.0.0 <10.0.0",
"node" : ">=20.0.0 <21.0.0"
},

I also ran npm cache clean -f but that didn't help
So, why does the system think I am using node v19.9.0? I have searched the entire project folder for '19.9.0' and not found anything. I have also rebooted the PC.
If I run npm update vue in the original project it's quite happy, no `Unsupported engine' message.

There are different ways of removing several Node versions (out of nvm) depending on your OS. On Linux, using find is a good start. There are also some very specific folders where Node tend to install itself in.

OP updated his nvm-windows, hence solving the issue of using the proper version of Node.

First off, you can uninstall every version of Node you have on your computer
Then you should install nvm to manage your Node versions. You'll be able to install, remove, and set new ones very easily and quickly.
Proceed with:

nvm install 20
nvm use 20

That will set the node version to v20 in the local project you are in. You can double-check that by running node -v in the project you want to upgrade the dependencies in.
You could also have a globally defined version with something like nvm alias default 20.10.0.

As for the Vue upgrade, go to the package.json file and bump the version there.
Then run npm install to update the dependencies.

The engines part in the package.json is more of a check for when you use npm but not gonna do the Node install for you. Good safeguard to prevent people using the wrong version tho!

Already done nvm install 20 and nvm use 20 - that's how I got the output from nvm ls in my question. Tried  nvm alias.... but that command not recognised (Windows OS)

@quilkin nvm ls is to list all the installed Node instances, nothing related to the instances you already have installed. Check this, maybe it's better to use nvm-windows? Otherwise, WSL2 should be fine to use as in a Linux context. Right now, the goal is to remove all the other instances of Node that you somehow installed before, like the 19.9.0. What do you have if you node -v?

I was using `nvm-windows' but an old version, updating it has solved that problem, thanks. Still cannot update Vue (stuck on 3.3.12) but that's another question.....

@quilkin I've updated my answer! Why are you stuck there? Packages incompatibility (with the ranges) or something else?

OK I forgot to bump package.json - but still confused; in my earlier project I didn't  need to do that: package.json still has "vue": "^3.2.0" whereas npm list has vue@3.4.26. And it's definately running 3.4 because it uses a 3.4 only feature.

@quilkin as a reminder, "^3.x.x" means anything under v4 so if anything like 3.99.99 is released tomorrow, it will still be included in "^3.2.0" if you npm install. You need a strict precise version otherwise. Good reference for that topic.

Understood, but I had to change package.json from "vue": "^3.3.0" to "vue": "^3.4.26", as well as giving the npm update command. According to that reference I shouldn't have needed to?

You are supposed to be able to just update for it to bump to the latest range according to the symbol in your package.json. But again, depends on the settings of your project, maybe you have something specific. I just tried on mine, works perfectly. Btw, for NPM you can also use this nice little project to help you with more visual upgrades: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-upgrade
